# Wait.until doesn't work in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried this code:

```
By by7 = By.xpath(".//*[@id='i2']/div[2]/div[1]");
WebDriverWait wait7 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement elem7 = wait7.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by7));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='i2']/div[2]/div[1]")).click();
```

But when i execute this code i'm taking `ElementNotVisibleException`

> Command duration or timeout: 11 milisecond

How can i pass this exception?

Comment: Make sure you don't user ajax. If there is ajax (jQuary) then you have to wait for it.

Comment: Oh i didn't know is this ajax code. What can i do in java to wait until visible element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for an element to be clickable is independent of waiting for it to be visible. You might need to make sure you have the right element and that it should be/will become visible. You can vary your `wait.until()` to wait for the element to become visible.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by7))
```

Just an FYI... your last statement, you can use the element that is returned from the `wait.until()` and click it. Do this: `elem7.click();` I don't know if that will solve your problem, just an efficiency that I noticed.

So the updated code would be

```
By by7 = By.xpath(".//*[@id='i2']/div[2]/div[1]");
WebDriverWait wait7 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement elem7 = wait7.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by7));
elem7.click();
```